# How would I go about replacing this disposal from a power source standpoint

Tags: garbage-disposal

I am about to try to replace my garbage disposal where the motor has stopped working.  I am replacing Insinkerator for Insinkerator.  I would rather not do it, but am going to attempt it.  In seeing that the power cord usually does not come with the new model, that got me wondering when I swap out the old to put in the new how do I do that because what I see running into the disposal is as shown in the included image.  You can see how one end goes into the disposal.  The other end runs outside the sink area and out of sight to the dishwasher area, so there is no receptacle it connects to directly.  How would I go about disconnecting power of the old one and then dealing with connecting power to the new one?

[image]

Comment: Find the breaker that provides power and turn it off.  Double check that the power is off before touching wires/cable, a multi-meter or non-contact voltage tester would come in handy for this, since unit does not work.  Never trust switches safety for power being off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually easiest to drop the disposer, turn it over, then remove the access cover and disconnect the disposal wires. Then reverse the order to re-install. Sometimes a new connector is in order.

If you pick a new disposal rated the same or less amps and horsepower you will likely not run up against code issues, but if you pick a larger one then you may have to look into shared/dedicated circuit issues and switch ratings.

Another option is to mount a junction box and receptacle under the sink and attach a cord to the disposal. The 2020 NEC doesn't specifically call out for GFCI protection, but it is obviously within 6' of a sink so required.

Comment: I was ready to disconnect the old one and reinstall in the new one, but the screw holding on the cover won't come out.   So I can't get the power disconnected from the old one.